# USB ports don't work during installation.

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, drivers, usb, system-installation

I am a new user and I have Windows 7. I tried to install Ubuntu 14.10, I have done it before with success, but my keyboard, mouse and wifi antenna weren't working. They are all connected in USB ports. I download two different versions, I think they were 13.10 and 12.04, but the same thing happened. This was by a CD installation. I tried a bootable USB flash drive, but of course it wouldn't even launch the installation. For some reason it won't recognize my USB ports and I can't do much to fix it, since I don't have internet without a USB port. Does anyone have any insight? I think this kind of question has been asked before, but I wasn't able to apply the solutions proposed, since I couldn't even use my keyboard. My system is pretty good, and I only have one PS/2 port. Thank you, and if it has been asked and solved, I am terribly sorry and I will delete the post. Cheers.

Comment: Not a full answer, but if you have a PS/2 keyboard you could try to use it and see if you can type text in or move around the user interface with the TAB key.

Comment: I think the main issue is that OP requires drivers in order to install, but needs internet access for the drivers, and the internet is supplied via USB.  So the question becomes, how can OP have the drivers ready-in-advance (probably off of Win7 machine).

Comment: Clayton, that's exactly what I was thinking. Well, I have three operating systems right now, Windows 7, Ubuntu and Kali Linux, but the USB ports only work in Windows, so it's definitely about the Linux OS's. The problem is that I don't know which drivers are required. If you could help me with that, I would really appreciate it.